# PHP MySQL updating varying amount of inputs

Tags: php, mysql

i'm wondering how am i suppose to update my database data of different records with different amount of inputs, what i'm trying to do is to create a system which list out records with the same property and you may choose to change any info within.

Something like an admin option which list out all the members and you're able to change their active and inactive status kinda thing.

I've always done with one record per update but never really tried making multiple records updates.

```
<table width="760px">
<?
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE (post != "1") AND (team = "'.$teamname.'")');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$post = $row['post'];

echo '<tr>
    <td width="120px">'.$row['username'].'</td>
    <td width="20px">:</td>
    <td>
<select class="inputboxr" style="width: 206px;" name="rank">
  <option value="2" ';Ppost('2'); echo'>Vice Captain</option>
  <option value="3" ';Ppost('3'); echo'>P.R. Officer</option>
  <option value="4" ';Ppost('4'); echo'>Senior Members</option>
  <option value="5" ';Ppost('5'); echo'>Members</option>
  <option value="0" ';Ppost('0'); echo'>New Recruit</option>
  </select>
  </td>
</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

but if i were to submit this form, i can't use $_POST['rank']; for each members will have different records, so should be something like rank1, rank2, rank3 for user1, user2, user3. I'm just not so sure how it should be done, any help :) ?

[image]

So an image example is this, how should i code my update mysql when i have more than 1 users to update from which uses the same field name?

Comment: at least include some example of your update sql and the relevant code

Comment: exactly, but i just haven't done my update sql, because i'm not sure how i am suppose to start with, because i always worked with one update, like 

UPDATE members SET blah="blah" WHERE username="username"

but now what i am doing is something like

UPDATE members SET blah="blah" WHERE username="username"
UPDATE members SET blah="blah2" WHERE username="username2"
UPDATE members SET blah="blah3" WHERE username="username3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In single query

```
update members
set blah = 
(
  case username
  when ... then "$val1"
  when ... then "$val2"
  end
)
where username in (...);
```

Comment: thanks, i'm exploring these fields and not sure how to put it in my sentence above.